# How to identify neighbors with some conditions

Tags: netlogo, social-networking

I'm trying to set up a toy model of connected turtles. Every turtle has a random belief [0,1] and I want to implement some conditions:

- If it's a turtle with belief > .5 the turtle doesn't do anything.
- If it's a turtle with belief < .5 and one of their immediate neighbour has a belief > .5, their new belief (of the turtle with belief < .5) would be belief + .1.
- If the turtle with belief < .5 doesn't have an immediate neighbour with belief > .5, the turtle doesn't do anything.

The basic setup:

```
turtles-own [belief]

to setup
  ca
  reset-ticks
  crt 5 [
   set shape "person"
   layout-circle turtles 5
   set belief random-float 1
   ]

ask turtles [ create-links-with min-n-of 2 other turtles [distance myself] ]

end
```

This creates a 5 turtles cycle network. Now they have to check the beliefs of their (two) closest neighbors. I tried this:

```
to go

ask turtles with [one-of link-neighbors with [belief > .5]] [

set belief belief + .1
]

end
```

So the basic idea is that every turtle with a connected neighbour with belief > .5 has to add .1 to its own belief. I have tried several variations of the `ask turtles with` line, but it always shows me a runtime error of this sort: WITH expected a true/false value from (turtle 0), but got (turtle 2) instead. Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`one-of`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#one-of) returns an agent. It is not suitable in this case for evaluating a condition with `with`- the condition is incomplete, since the line `ask turtles with [one-of link-neighbors with [belief > .5]]` translates (roughly) to "ask turtles with the condition turtle x to do something".

I think what you're after is something that uses `count` to count the number of believing `turtles` or `any?` to evaluate if an agentset exists:

```
to go-1
  ask turtles with [ (count link-neighbors with [belief > 0.5]) > 0 ] [
    set belief belief + 0.1
  ]
end

to go-2
  ask turtles with [ any? link-neighbors with [ belief > 0.5 ] ] [
    set belief belief + 0.1
  ]  
end
```

Comment: Nice, the `any? link-neighbors with` works as intended! Thank you very much!